# Sample Hibernate program?

Tags: hibernate

How would I write a simple program using Hibernate in Java, with MySQL as a backend?

Answer (score 4):

The [Hibernate reference docs](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/reference/en-US/html/) are a good place to start.

Maybe a ["Hello, Hibernate"](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2004/jw-1018-hibernate.html) can help.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Duffymo's suggestion, I would recommend trying out Netbeans 6.5. I am just starting out with hibernate as well. Netbeans automates database mapping and seems to integrate well with Hibernate. It has helped ease me into the framework.

Comment: IntelliJ has good support as well, but it is not free :)  I don't know about automating, but I think the Hibernate folks offer some tools for that.